# ubuntu 22.04: UBSAN: invalid-load of _Bool in mac80211

Tags: boot, drivers, wireless, 22.04, dmesg

I upgraded 21.10 (Stock) to 22.04 for an Ausus ROG Strix Advantage Laptop.
I Notice this error in dmesg:

**UBSAN: invalid-load in /build/linux-HMZHpV/linux-5.15.0/net/mac80211/status.c:1164:21
load of value 255 is not a valid value for type '_Bool'**

CPU: 2 PID: 813 Comm: napi/phy0-8196 Not tainted 5.15.0-27-generic #28-Ubuntu
[    7.831787] Hardware name: ASUSTeK COMPUTER INC. ROG Strix G513QY_G513QY/G513QY, BIOS G513QY.316 11/29/2021

The wireless does work.

Where can I report this issue ?

Comment: It appears that the kernel developers are already aware of it: https://www.mail-archive.com/kernel-packages@lists.launchpad.net/msg475875.html You might also report it here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/  Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: Similar message during boot-up "UBSAN: invalid-load/build/linux-WD899k/linux-5.15.0/net/mac80211/status.c:1164:21 load of value 255 is not a valid value for type '_Bool'" Hardware Acer Aspire Intel Core i5-480M. Doesn't seem to cause any issue. Ubuntu 22.04 upgraded from 21.10

Comment: Similar problem with ath5k. [Reported here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1972140).

Comment: same problem on lenovo legion 5 pro